# IE gaps when rendering html table cell with radius border nested in other table

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, html-table, radius

In IE (version 11 and likely older versions), I get a small vertical and/or horizontal gaps (or lines) in the border when I am using a radius on a TD in a nested table.  The same problem occurs if I used a radius on DIV nested in a table.  If I use Zoom function in IE, the lines will appear or display depending on the Zoom level.  There is no problem in Firefox nor Chrome.  And I am using the nesting, because I need the background color near the radius to be different than the background color of the enclosing table.

Here is a screenshot of the white line error:

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Here is sample code:

```
<table style="width:50%;" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <td style="background-color:#292F6C;">
            sadasd
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
<td style="background-color: white;padding: 0px;border:0px;">
    <table style="border-spacing:0px;width:100%;height: 10px;">
        <tr>
            <td style="background-color:#292F6C;-webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 11px;-moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 11px;border-bottom-left-radius: 11px;"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/f7e6qo1m/

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Figured out that adding a 1px border on the square sides seems to fix the problem.

https://jsfiddle.net/f7e6qo1m/1/

```
    <table style="width:50%;" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
            <td style="background-color:#292F6C;">
                sadasd
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
<td style="background-color: white;padding: 0px;border:0px;">
    <table style="border-spacing:0px;width:100%;height: 10px;">
        <tr>
            <td style="background-color:#292F6C;-webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 11px;-moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 11px;border-bottom-left-radius: 11px;border-top: 1px solid #292F6C;border-right: 1px solid #292F6C;"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```